# Attempted an Unsupported Operation Using Serial port

Tags: port, upgrade, communication

I am recompiling an application from Visual C++ 6.0 in Visual Studio 2015. It is using Mscomm as serial communication library. Everything gets compiled fine but when I run the program, I get "Attempted an Unsupported Operation" twice. Upon debugging I found out the culprit is the following snippet:

```
   void CFFLSView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
    {
        CFormView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
        //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CFFLSView)
        DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MSCOMM1, m_comm);
        DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_MSCOMM2, m_comm2);
        //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
    }
```

This calls m_comm and m_comm2 to be open COM1 and COM2. I don't have the equipment connected to my computer now, and I will have to test the compiled software at site tomorrow. I suspect that because nothing is connected to COM1 and COM2, the program cannot open port and returns that error but I am not sure that is the case, getting in the site is very difficult and I only have one opportunity to go in and test the software there. I want to make sure that this error is only given because nothing is connected to COM1 and COM2 and not any other problem. I appreciate your comments and thoughts on this. If it helps, the DDX_Control function calls the following function in debug mode:

```
void CMSComm::SetPortOpen(BOOL bNewValue)
{
    static BYTE parms[] =
        VTS_BOOL;
    InvokeHelper(0x14, DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, VT_EMPTY, NULL, parms,
         bNewValue);
}
```

which is supposed to open the port.